# Adminer error (No PHP extension supported (SQLSRV, MSSQL) available

Tags: linux, database-administration

Adminer is a db management tool made in php (http://www.adminer.org/)

I've installed it in Linux LAMP but I get the same error I've written in the Question Title.

Did anybody solve this?

How?

I am on Debian Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually easier than that...

Instead of manually installing and dealing with dependencies and errors inferno I've installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install adminer
```

Comment: I think this may not be the solution to the question as you need to install php drivers for Adminer to work. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error is saying. Your PHP is installed/compiled without SQL extension support.

To find out what extensions you have.
Add a new file in your documents path, call it something like myphpinfo.php

Edit the file and paste this code in it.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save the file.
From your browser, go to

```
http://yourserver/path/to/myphpinfo.php
```

You should see details about your installation of php

Depending on what Debian version you are running, you can install the extension you want, or if you want, you can compile PHP again to add/enable those extensions.

Comment: I get it but this is not a complete solution...
Which extension should I install? How?

Comment: You didn't mention what debian version you have, how was your lamp installed. Without such details, I can't help.

Comment: I have Debian 7.0 and lamp was installed using this wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/LaMp